# Unable to Open Proccess with PID 4 , problem port 80 and Apache

Tags: php, android, apache, api, pid

Problem detected! 3:19:55 AM [Apache] Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4! 3:19:55 AM [Apache] Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free! 3:19:55 AM [Apache] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application 3:19:55 AM [Apache] or configure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

How can i solve the php control panel PID problem.

Comment: Your system is trying to start apache to listen on port 80, but something else is already using port 80 - perhaps another apache instance that did not start cleanly. Troubleshooting will vary quite a lot depending on your environment, but you did not give any information about that. For instance, can we assume you are booting the server when this happens? What OS are you running, and how was apache installed?

Answer (score 0):

can you tell me about your envirenment please ?

if you are running on localhost use the 8080 port instead of 80

if you are running on linux such as ubuntu 
try to run this cmd
fuser -n tcp -k 80
it's will close all the process on the 80 port

Comment: What OS you are running the apache on ? , windows ? linux ? on a vps ? on your pc ? please tell us more

Comment: so it's a localhost , you can not run on the 80 port on your windows , so change the port to 8080 and it's will work

Answer (score 0):

Using Powershell you can find a process by port:

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 80).OwningProcess
```

If System is the process opening that port then usually another service has requested this. Here is a list of possible processes:

- SQL Server Reporting Services (ReportServer)
- Web Deployment Agent Service (MsDepSvc)
- BranchCache (PeerDistSvc)
- Sync Share Service (SyncShareSvc)
- World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)
- Internet Information Server (WAS, IISADMIN)